# DRF Serializer boolean field not saving model default

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using **Django 2.2**

I have a model with a boolean field

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
```

and serializer

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            'is_active'
        ]

    def validate(self, attrs):
        print('attrs: {}'.format(attrs))
        return super().validate(attrs)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('validated_data: {}'.format(validated_data))
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Even though the model `is_active` field is default set to `True`, the `attrs` in the `validate()` method and `validated_data` inside the `create()` method contains `is_active` as `False` if `is_active` is not explicitly sent with the request.

To set the default to `True`, I need to add explicitly serializer field to the serializer class

```
is_active = serializers.BooleanField(default=True, required=False)
```

**Why doesn't it set the default value of the model field?**

Comment: what was the print output inside the **`validate`** method?

Comment: It gave `{'is_active': False}`

Comment: What was the payload?

Comment: Payload doesn't contain `is_active` field. Also removing `is_active` from the `fields` list is working fine and default value is being saved.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't it set the default value of the model field?

Most likely because you are sending html form data and that HTML specs says a missing boolean means it is false. if a boolean is in the form payload, it means it's true.

Therefore, the default value will only work with anything except HTMl forms.

Django has a builtin workaround with [`NullBooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#nullbooleanfield) and so does [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#nullbooleanfield) although they are different and will appear as drop down.